# Manage different class inserts and updates in transaction boundary in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I am working on a project in which I have created classes like Students, Subjects, Classes, Courses, etc. All of these classes have a constructor in which I pass `$db` because all the classes do their own inserts and updates, which is working fine.

Now my problem is how I should manage transaction in this kind of structure? I don't want to write all inserts and updates in a single class, I want them in their own classes.

Comment: way too broad of a question

Answer (score 1):

Using the transactionality features in the DBO object you can still have the actual queries themselves take place in their respective objects, as long as you first start the transaction, and then commit or roll back as all objects have been traversed. You will be passing an instantiated PDO object as your $db.

See here for documentation:
[php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php)

A random example:

```php
$dbo = new PDO(...); // init connection
$student = new Student($dbo, 1); // retrieves student where id=1 from table
$subject = new Subject($dbo, 1); // retrieves subject where id=1 from table

$student->setName('Bart');
$subject->setName('Nose picking 101');

$dbo->beginTransaction();
$student->store(); // executes an update on $dbo
$subject->store(); // ...
$db->commit(); // or ->rollBack(); in case something didn't go as planned
```